# Spring Boot: How to Update Beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a @Bean which calls an external API at the start of the application. How can I have it such that it makes a new call and updates the bean on a set timer?

```
@Bean
public Template apiCall()
{
    final String uri = "http://...";
    return new RestTemplate().getForObject(uri,Template.class);
}
```

Comment: create private class variable and update with System's time at your interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is reload the template in some kind of factory bean.

```java
@Component
public class TemplateProvider {

   @Value("${template.uri}")
   private String uri;

   private Template template;

   @Autowired 
   private RestTemplate restTemplate;

   @PostConstruct
   init () {
      loadTemplate();
   }

   public synchronized void reset() {
      loadTemplate();
   }

   public synchronized Template template() {
      return template;
   }

   private void loadTemplate() {
     try {
        this.template = restTemplate.getFor...();
     } 
     catch (Exception e) {
         //
     }
   }

}
```

Then you can call `reset()` inside a `@scheduled` method.

The only drawback to this is that callers should not keep reference of `Template` in their state.. Always access template via the provider to avoid inconsistency problems.

```java
public class Client {
   @Autowired
   private TemplateProvider templateProvider;

   public void method() {
      templateProvider.template().method();
   }
}
```

Comment: it's a bit late to comment on this but you have saved me so much headaches, thank you a billion times! You're the best!!